# Streamline add/remove child MovieClips from an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, variables, movieclip, removechild

I'm currently trying to make an Interactive Storybook based on several tutorials I've been working on the past few months, but before I continue with the expanded project, there are a few things I'd like to change and streamline. Below is a simplified version of the original tutorial, and after that is where I currently am in making modifications.

```
    package
    {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        public class Main_Test extends MovieClip
        {
            var startPage:StartPage;
            var hillPage:HillPage;
            var pondPage:PondPage;

            public function Main_Test()
            {
                startPage = new StartPage;
                hillPage = new HillPage;
                pondPage = new PondPage;
                addChild(startPage); 

                // add event listeners
                startPage.hillButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onHillButtonClick);
                startPage.pondButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPondButtonClick);
                hillPage.backToStartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBackButtonClick_Hill);
                pondPage.backToStartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBackButtonClick_Pond);
            }

            // event handlers
            function onHillButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                addChild(hillPage);
                removeChild(startPage);
            }
            function onPondButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                addChild(pondPage);
                removeChild(startPage);
            }
            function onBackButtonClick_Hill(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                addChild(startPage);
                removeChild(hillPage);
            }
            function onBackButtonClick_Pond(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                addChild(startPage);
                removeChild(pondPage);
            }
        }
}
```

---

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main_Test_2 extends MovieClip
    {
        var pages:Array = ["startPage", "hillPage", "pondPage"];

        public function Main_Test_2()
        {
            pages[0] = new StartPage;
            pages[1] = new HillPage;
            pages[2] = new PondPage;
            addChild(pages[0]); 
            /*trace (pages[0]);*/

            // add event listeners
            pages[0].hillButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hillButtonClick);
            pages[0].pondButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pondButtonClick);
            pages[1].homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeButtonClick);
            pages[2].homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeButtonClick);
        }


        function hillButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace ("You did a thing.");
            addChild(pages[1]); 
            removeChild(pages[0]); 
        }
        function pondButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace ("Slimy frogs are slimy.");
            addChild(pages[2]); 
            removeChild(pages[0]); 
        }
        function homeButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            /*addChild(pages[0]); */
            if (pages[1])
            {
                trace ("All your base are belong to me.");
                /*removeChild(pages[1]);*/
            }
            if (pages[2])
            {
                trace ("You are who you choose to be.");
                /*removeChild(pages[2]);*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing I did was switch from individual variables for each page to an array. When I made a 9 page 3x3 version of the interactive storybook, the code got out of hand and was really repetitive, so I figured the array would shorten things, but that brings me to the second thing I'm trying to do and couldn't figure out even before switching to an array. In the tutorial, each button within a MovieClip adds the next page with addChild and removes the current page with removeChild, but these buttons are setup so they can do different things based on the page they are on when being clicked, which results in multiple onBackButtonClick results, for example. This becomes a problem as the number of pages increase. I'd rather have each button add the page corresponding to the button while removing ALL other pages, so I don't need to have multiple redundant buttons like the onBackButtonClick_hill and onBackButtonClick_pond. I tried setting this up on my own with the second batch of code, but I can't get it to work properly.

I was also thinking about making a few variables, including var currentPage, var allPages, and var allOtherPages (currentPage - allPages), so I can tell the buttons to do things like add current page and remove all other pages, but I don't know how to refer to the current movieclip on stage as the current page, etc. I'm still too new at programming.

Any help with these issues and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going the right way. If you spend some more time, you can figure out how to optimize it.

First, use the array of page objects (not names):

```
var pages:Array = [new startPage(), new hillPage(), new pondPage()];
```

Next, you can arrange a 3x3 (or any other) page output in an efficient way using loops.

```
const GRID_SIZE:int = 3;
for (var i:int = 0; i < pages.lengthl i++) {
    var page:MovieClip = pages[i] as MovieClip;
    page.x = (i % GRID_SIZE) * (page.width + 10);
    page.y = Math.floor(i / GRID_SIZE) * (page.height + 10);
    addChild(page);
    page.homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, homeButtonClick, false, 0, true);
}
```

So, you can place as many pages as you want, and also you're adding listeners for each page in an efficient way. Inside the listener, use:

```
function homeButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var t:MovieClip = event.target.parent as MovieClip;
    if (t is hillPage) {
        // ... do something for the hillPage
    } else if (t is pondPage) {
        // ... do something for the pondPage
    } else {
        // ... and so on
    }
    navigateBack();
}
```

Now you can also see that there is a new function navigateBack which is used, naturally, for navigating back.

All you have to do is to remember the last page to which you must return. Note that it may not be the start page if you wish. Also you can remember not one page, but a history of pages - again, if you wish. Let's just create an array of visited pages:

```
var pageStack:Array = [];
```

Every time you go to some page, you can put it to pageStack:

```
pageStack.push(page);
```

Every time you need to go back, you use the navigateBack function:

```
function navigateBack():void {
    var page:MovieClip = pageStack.pop();
    // it is your current page, so destroy it
    removeChild(page);
    // also remove listeners, if you want...
    // now retrieve the previous page
    var pl:int = pageStack.length;
    if (pl) {
        page = pageStack[pl - 1];
    } else {
        page = pages[0];
    }
    addChild(page);
}
```

You can also modify the navigateBack function to destroy not only current page but all previous pages, etc.

Comment: I attacked this code for another day or two and eventually figured it out. Thanks everyone for the help.